# Shorten JSON reading class

Tags: c#, json, optimization, json.net

I have a simple JSON reading class that should grab values from a JSON object and put it in c# variables. Right now it uses 8 if statements, but I was wondering if this can be done in a smoother way.

current code:

```
public Game Read(string filePath)
    {
        string fileName = "./Levels/TempleOfDoom.json";

        JObject json = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(fileName));

        Game game = new Game();

        foreach (JObject jconnection in json["rooms"])
        {
            Room room = new Room();
            foreach (JProperty jProperty in jconnection.Children().OfType<JProperty>())
            {
                if (jProperty.Name == "id")
                    room.id = jProperty.Value.ToObject<int>();

                if (jProperty.Name == "width")
                    room.width = jProperty.Value.ToObject<int>();

                if (jProperty.Name == "height")
                    room.height = jProperty.Value.ToObject<int>();

                foreach (JObject jconnection2 in jconnection["items"])
                {
                    Item item = new Item();
                    foreach (JProperty jProperty2 in jconnection.Children().OfType<JProperty>())
                    {
                        if (jProperty.Name == "type")
                            item.type = jProperty2.Value.ToObject<string>();

                        if (jProperty.Name == "x")
                            item.x = jProperty2.Value.ToObject<int>();

                        if (jProperty.Name == "y")
                            item.y = jProperty2.Value.ToObject<int>();

                        if (jProperty.Name == "damage")
                            item.damage = jProperty2.Value.ToObject<int>();

                        if (jProperty.Name == "color")
                            item.color = jProperty2.Value.ToObject<string>();
                    }
                }
            }
            game.Rooms.Add(room);
        }

        return game;
    }
```

relevant part of JSON object:

```
{
"rooms": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "room",
        "width": 5,
        "height": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "room",
        "width": 3,
        "height": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "type": "room",
        "width": 5,
        "height": 5,
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "disappearing boobietrap",
                "damage": 1,
                "x": 2,
                "y": 1
            },
            {
                "type": "sankara stone",
                "x": 2,
                "y": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "type": "room",
        "width": 11,
        "height": 7,
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "key",
                "color": "green",
                "x": 1,
                "y": 1
            },
            {
                "type": "sankara stone",
                "x": 5,
                "y": 3
            },
            {
                "type": "boobietrap",
                "damage": 1,
                "x": 4,
                "y": 2
            },
            {
                "type": "boobietrap",
                "damage": 1,
                "x": 5,
                "y": 2
            },
            {
                "type": "boobietrap",
                "damage": 1,
                "x": 6,
                "y": 2
            },
            {
                "type": "boobietrap",
                "damage": 1,
                "x": 4,
                "y": 4
            },
            {
                "type": "boobietrap",
                "damage": 1,
                "x": 5,
                "y": 4
            },
            {
                "type": "boobietrap",
                "damage": 1,
                "x": 6,
                "y": 4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "type": "room",
        "width": 5,
        "height": 5,
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "key",
                "color": "red",
                "x": 2,
                "y": 3
            },
            {
                "type": "sankara stone",
                "x": 2,
                "y": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "type": "room",
        "width": 3,
        "height": 3,
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "sankara stone",
                "x": 1,
                "y": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "type": "room",
        "width": 5,
        "height": 3,
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "pressure plate",
                "x": 2,
                "y": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "type": "room",
        "width": 3,
        "height": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "type": "room",
        "width": 5,
        "height": 5,
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "sankara stone",
                "x": 2,
                "y": 2
            },
            {
                "type": "boobietrap",
                "damage": 1,
                "x": 1,
                "y": 3
            },
            {
                "type": "boobietrap",
                "damage": 1,
                "x": 2,
                "y": 3
            },
            {
                "type": "boobietrap",
                "damage": 1,
                "x": 3,
                "y": 3
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

}

As you can see, each room has an ID, width and height (type can be ignored) and some rooms have items, which all have a type, x and y coordinate, and some have colors or damage numbers. Is there a better way to get all of these values into a C# class? A game has a List of rooms, and each room can possibly have a list of items.

EDIT: Thanks guys! These lines of code did exactly what I wanted (together with  some extra classes for each object game/player/item etc.

```
public Game Read(string fileName)
    {
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Game>(json.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: A more conventional approach would be to create a `Room` type and an `Item` type, along with a `Game` with a `List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }` property, add appropriate attributes if necessary, then call `JsonConverter.DeserializeObject<Game>`. It will all just be sorted for you. See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm or other Json.NET tutorials.

Comment: @Jon Skeet seems good, and another suggesting is to use System.Reflection and dynamicly set the values by name. tell me if you need me to make an example

Comment: @Alen.Toma: Why reinvent the wheel? `JsonConvert` already uses reflection...

Comment: Yes I know that why i said that @Jon Skeet Suggesting seems is good, I just wanted to give another way to do it if he wanted to.

Comment: What does the `Room` data model look like?

Comment: In your "solution" you are actually parsing the JSON twice, which you don't need to do.  You can get rid of the `JObject` and just do `return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Game>(File.ReadAllText(fileName));`

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to use a webpage called https://json2csharp.com/ that it will create the model class for your json. Sometimes it needs a little tweaking, then is as easy as calling

```
var json = JsonConverter.DeserializeObject<YourJsonClass>(File.ReadAllText(fileName))
```

And you would have a class representing your json file, and if you still need to move this information to your custom classes you wouldnt need the if at all just do something like

```
foreach (var jsonRoom in json.Rooms)
{
   room.id = jsonRoom.id;
   //and so on
}
```

Comment: The OP is already using Newtonsoft.Json - the question is tagged `json.net` and the OP's existing code uses `JProperty` etc. I would suggest removing the first part of your answer.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, i edited the answer acordingly. I ll keep the json2csharp link because it may help him, and since OP didnt share those classes, im not sure they are working with the json model

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class, for example:

```
public class Item
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int damage { get; set; }
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
}

public class Room
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public List<Room> rooms { get; set; }
}
```

And then deserialize the object as:

```
MyClass myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json.ToString());
```

And then you can access all inside of `MyClass` and iterate over `List<Room>` using `foreach`